# Devise Bootstrap Modal Link and Error catching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, simple-form

I have altered the standard devise sign up and login forms to put them inside bootstrap modals. They are in simple forms because I read a blog about easier formatting (but I am yet to see the value in that form gem). I now have two problems that I can't solve.

The first is that in my login form, I have a link that says 'not yet registered? Sign up here'. That should link to the registration form. However, I moved that content so that the modal trigger and its content were in the same form. It's now in devise/shared/registration items. The standard registrations_new is redundant.

This link gives me an error and I can't see what the problem with it is. I'm trying to point to a view partial in devise/shared/registration_items.

```
<%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
             <%= link_to "Not yet registered? Sign up", shared_registration_items_path %><br />
            <% end -%>
```

I'm really not understanding why the controller name can't be registrations. That controller is what houses the 'create' method for new registrations.

The second problem is that if there are errors in the sign up form - they are not identified. When the form was just a new page, the errors were flagged. Now that the form is in a modal, I can't find a way to get them to display.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i think the error is in the helpers of devise, devise just load this in devise views, so now that you are trying to access them in other views you should recreate them for your application or replace the functions in your forms, this is easy in your **application_helper.rb** put this

```
def resource_name
   :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

Of course you can just hardcode this in the forms, but the devise wiki recommends this method.

Now you can create your partials with the modal forms, i render this ones in my layout because i usually have those for my navbars and like to be access from all my views, you can just edit the behavior with *user_sing_in?* method, i will just copy and paste a modal from one of my projects

```
<div class="modal fade" id="sign_in_modal_user">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path, :role => "form" ) do |f| %>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="modal-title">Sign in</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <%= f.label :email %>
                <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :class => "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <%= f.label :password %>
                <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> 
                <%= f.label :remember_me, "Recordarme" %>
            </div>

            <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_user_password_path %>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sign_up_modal_user">Sign Up?</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <%= f.submit "Sing in!", :class => "btn btn-info" %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

in this example i have two modals, one for register and one for sing in in my partial, i call each one from the other, if you look the register button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sign_up_modal_user">Sign Up?</button>
```

you will see that goes to the other modal(is pretty much like the sign in one, but with the registration new path and password confirmation).

A couple of thinks to considerate:

- If the sign in or the sign up forms fails it will redirect to the original ones, so you should have those ones too.
- You can improve this with a gem called *gem 'client_side_validations'*, this one will do client side validations before submit, and prevent the error before trigger the form, so just in weird cases you will go to the original forms.

I didn't put my original sign up form because have another extra items that just go out of the point of interest and it seems that it will be more clear with just one example, hope it helps, regards!